# Referencing Listview Null Adapter

Tags: java, android, widget, expandablelistview

Im beginner android developer and trying on implementing ExpandableListView into my app but kept getting the error message. already done double checking and maybe my logic is weak that i could not identify the issue. Much appreciate that you could help me out or guide me the right way. Thanks <3

i found a reference link:
[link](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

Error:

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ExpandableListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.n3333.myapplication.ExpendableList.onCreate(ExpendableList.java:31)
```

it stated that the list Adapter is null:

[image]

MyCodes:

List_Item xml:

[image]

List_Group xml:

[image]

Main Activity Class:

```
public class ExpendableList extends AppCompatActivity {
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // get the listview
    expListView = findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    // preparing list data
  prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

/*
 * Preparing the list data
 */
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
    listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
    listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
    top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
    top250.add("The Godfather");
    top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
    top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
    top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
    top250.add("The Dark Knight");
    top250.add("12 Angry Men");

    List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
    nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
    nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
    nowShowing.add("Turbo");
    nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
    nowShowing.add("Red 2");
    nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

    List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
    comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
    comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
    comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
    comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
    comingSoon.add("Europa Report");

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), comingSoon);
  }
}
```

Adapter Class:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.header);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}


@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.child);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi all, false alarm. i know the reason.

I accidentally removed setContentView(R.layout.activity_expendable_listview); in my ExpandableList activity.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code to your main activity xml.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f4f4f4" >

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/lvExp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>   

</LinearLayout>
```